# pandas merge returning incoherent result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, merge

Today, I'm facing some difficulties with pandas merge.

here's my problem.

I do have 3 CSV files.

One of them has a liste of storeIDs and a list of productIDs for each stores like :

| storeID | ProductID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |

The second csv data is a list of videos. that also contain storeID. and a category because the videos are recorded in a unique aisle.

| storeID | videoID | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | chocolate |
| 1 | 2 | milk |
| 2 | 3 | chocolate |
| 2 | 4 | candies |

my third csv got the same data than the second expect categories but mention the device which was used to record the video.

Here's my actual code.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

# Set your directories and file patterns
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
source_folder = os.path.join(script_dir, 'Exports BE')
assortiment_file_pattern = os.path.join(script_dir, 'Assortiment', 'NF_SUIVI_PRESENCE_ASSORTIMENT.csv')
complete_reports_file_pattern = os.path.join(source_folder, "Complete Reports*")
export_users_file_pattern = os.path.join(source_folder, "export-users*")

# Find your source files
assortiment_file = pd.read_csv(assortiment_file_pattern, delimiter=";")
complete_reports_file = glob.glob(complete_reports_file_pattern)[0]
export_users_file = glob.glob(export_users_file_pattern)[0]

# Load and preprocess the "NF_SUIVI_PRESENCE_ASSORTIMENT.csv" file
assortiment_df = assortiment_file[['CODESAP', 'EAN', 'STATUT']]
assortiment_df = assortiment_df[assortiment_df['STATUT'].isin(['D', 'N', 'O'])]
assortiment_df['STATUT'] = "NOT_DETECTED"
assortiment_df.rename(columns={'CODESAP': 'store_provider_id', 'STATUT': 'NAME'}, inplace=True)

# Load the "Complete Reports" and "export-users" files
reports_df = pd.read_csv(complete_reports_file, delimiter=";")
users_df = pd.read_csv(export_users_file, delimiter=";")

# Merge 'complete_reports' and 'export_users' using 'id' and 'REPORT_ID' as keys
merged_df = pd.merge(reports_df, users_df[['REPORT_ID', 'INPUT_SUBCATEGORIES']],
                     left_on='id', right_on='REPORT_ID', how='inner')

# Filter the merged DataFrame by device model and 'INPUT_SUBCATEGORIES'
allowed_models = ["iPhone12,1", "iPhone12,8", "iPhone13,2", "iPhone14,6"]
unique_categories = merged_df['INPUT_SUBCATEGORIES'].unique()
print("Unique categories: ")
for i, cat in enumerate(unique_categories):
    print(f"{i+1}. {cat}")
selected_cat_num = int(input("Enter the number of the category you want to select: "))
selected_category = unique_categories[selected_cat_num - 1]
filtered_df = merged_df[(merged_df['DeviceModel'].isin(allowed_models)) & (merged_df['INPUT_SUBCATEGORIES'] == selected_category)]

# Merge the filtered DataFrame with the "NF_SUIVI_PRESENCE_ASSORTIMENT.csv" file
final_df = pd.merge(filtered_df, assortiment_df, on='store_provider_id', how='inner')

# Create and save the final DataFrame
final_df['VALUE'] = '1'
final_df['AVAILABLE_FOR_DN'] = ''
final_df = final_df[['NAME', 'EAN', 'VALUE', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'store', 
                     'store_provider_id', 'date', 'app_version_code', 'id', 'video', 'AVAILABLE_FOR_DN']]
final_df = final_df.dropna(subset=['EAN'])
output_path = os.path.join(script_dir, '..', 'export-nestle-test.csv')
final_df.to_csv(output_path, index=False, sep=";")
```

the aim is to got a list of products, the video in which they're supposed to appear, and the category in which they're supposed to be.

My results are a complete mess because at the last merge it seems like the category choose by the user is applied to all products no matter what. and return me a way too big amount of data.

is my merge correct ? is merge a good method for such a need ?

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: Could you isolate the problem on your code, and only share the piece you have issues with? I'd suggest use test data directly on the code you share like:  product = pd.DataFrame({
    'storeId': ['1', '1', '2', '2'],
    'productId': ['1', '2', '1', '2'],
}) so it's easy to help you

Comment: Merge will return a row for all possible combinations of matches, so unless there is a one-to-one relationship between the left and right merge columns, you will end up with more rows than you started with (Also, by using an "inner" join you will lose any rows where there isn't a match - which may be what you want, but if not, using "left" or "outer" with indicator=True can be helpful to see what's happening).